# Fill out preallocated matrix in R

Tags: r

I am writing an R program where I'm adding a column to a matrix in each iteration of `repeat`. Because I choose `repeat` I do not have access to the current iteration number.
I could use `cbind` to create the matrix, but I know this is slow.
Are there ways to fill out a preallocated matrix by column without knowledge of the current index?

Comment: get the index of the first column not totally filled with NAs ? Or create a variable `ind` that you can increment in each iteration of repeat. Second option is probably the best (fastest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test the size of the matrix and increase its size by chunks. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=10)
i <- 1
repeat {
  if (i > nrow(mat)) mat <- rbind(mat, matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=10))
  x <- rnorm(1)
  y <- rnorm(1, mean=3)
  mat[i,] <- c(x, y)
  if (x > y) break
  i <- i+1  
}

mat[seq_len(i),]
```

Adjust the size of the chunks by which you increase the matrix to your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Roland your answer was helpfull. I asume there is no way to  do this over some `apply`.

Comment: You can't use `*apply` functions if you don't know the number of iterations.